# Expecting 60Hz with external monitor but only getting 30Hz

Tags: display, displayport, adapter, usb-c

Not sure this is the right place to ask. Please roast me if necessary.

My problem: connecting an external monitor to a Mac with USB-C and expecting 60Hz on monitor, but only getting 30Hz.

The monitor, the adaptor and the Mac support 60Hz.

- Monitor https://eu.aoc.com/en/monitors/u2879vf
- Adaptor
  https://www.mwave.com.au/product/startech-usb-typec-to-displayport-adapter-with-usb-power-delivery-4k-60hz-ac20887
- Mac (MacBook Pro 2019)

How might I diagnose this issue?

Comment: I'm trying a new DisplayPort cable that explicitly supports 60hz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I love Apple products but this is crazy.

I tried resetting the monitor and buying a new DP cable. No fix.

I *had* to OPTION-CLICK the 'scale' radio option within System Prefs > Displays.

THEN I had to check 'Low resolution modes'. And *only then* was I able to set 60Hz in the 'refresh rate' dropdown.

So there you go - the magic hidden option-click. Totally magic. Totally hidden. A relic of 90s OS interaction design. Not documented anywhere.

Comment: my eyes are thanking me already

Comment: Wow this is insane! It actually works! Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this problem:

I had to set the display resolution to "Default for Display". By doing this the display options will reset and the mac will be able to render 60Hz on the external monitor.

After the monitor resets to 60Hz then I could change the scaling to any option and it would still render 60Hz.